# redirecting http traffic to https with avoiding mixed content warnings

Tags: php, .htaccess, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a site which has recently had an SSL certificate installed on it.  The `.htaccess` file currently forces all traffic to use `http` and there are many hard coded links throughout the site, including references to `css` and `javascript` files.

Would it be safe just to change the `.htaccess` file to redirect all traffic to `https`?  I'm guessing that will give me mixed content warnings as some links will be served over `http` instead of `https`.

I am thinking maybe it would be best to change all the links to `src="//www.mysite.com"` first before changing the `.htaccess` file.  I appreciate that it would be better practice to update the httpd.conf file to include the SSL changes, I just don't want to break the live site.

I have also noticed that sometimes `css` and `javascript` changes aren't always downloaded when refreshing the page but if I view the page source and click on the source file it downloads and the site works fine.  Obviously I want to avoid this sort of situation when going live.

What would be the best way forward?

Comment: Since you have a SSL certificate, redirect all `http` requests to `https`. You should also be explicit and use `https://` throughout your application (in all `link href`, `script src`, `img src` etc...). Using relative protocols (just `//`) is discouraged since all traffic is recommended to go through  `https` nowadays.

Comment: Not just redirecting to the https but also consider about the www and not www version of your url to avoid duplicate content issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing .htaccess to redirect to https will not solve your problem. The browser will probably still see the http inside your html and produce the mixed content warning.

You will have to go through your templates and either switch to relative links, or to // or to https://

The fact that your static css and js files are not updated immediately is because browsers cache such files.

During dev, you can use ctrl+F5 for a hard refresh of the page to get fresh copies from the server.

A first solution is to append something like ?v=1 to the file urls. This will force the files to be downloaded every time you change the version. 
But keep in mind that old browsers might not cache files with GET parameters at all.

The super safe way would be to set the version on the static side of the url.

Like /js/assets.v1.js

Manually doing any of those options might be tedious, but it will be effective.

There are tools that can do this automatically every time you build your assets, but you might have to modify your templates even more for it to work properly. It really depends on what you are using.

Comment: _"A fast but not so proper solution for normal use is to append something like ?v=1"_ - In what way wouldn't that be proper? As long as you don't change the query string on each request, it will still cache it until the query string changes, which you only do when it's been updated (and forces all cached css/js to be reloaded, which they should be).

Comment: Files with get variables are not cached

Comment: Yes, they are. Browsers simply see it as a different filename. Why do you think many big libraries uses this strategy when serving their files through CDN?

Comment: That's based on an article that's 10 years old. That's pretty much an anti-issue today. Unless you're going to support IE6-7 and such, it's pretty safe to use.

Comment: Sorry i deleted that to phrase it differently. here is the link for the history https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#article-header-id-2

Comment: Yes, and that still refers to [this article](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/) from 2008. As they even phrase it on the page you posted to: "Query strings _didn't_ always work. Some browsers _didn't_ see a differnt query string as a different file.". They phrase it in past tense.

Comment: What I wanted to point out is that client compatibility is a different and big discussion. And setting a get variable vs setting a static file part version should be identical (automated or by hand). So why don't do it the super safe way and sleep better at night :)

Comment: But fair enough. It's not something to lose sleep any more. Thanks for pointing out to us. I will update my answer

Comment: switch to relative links, or to // or to https:// -> // not works. when if you are served as https. if the image link is http, then ...